# For collection types, why remove method returns a value while insert does't

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, collections, set

thanks for your time and attention to help me on this issue

I've noticed that, for collection types (Array, Set and Dictionary) the remove method always returns a value but the insert method does't, why is that, why not both of them returns a value. What is the desing logic behind this? I would like to know it.

```
var letterSet = Set<String>()
print(letterSet.insert("a")) // -> ()
print(letterSet.remove("a")) // -> Optional("a")

var intArray = [Int]()
print(intArray.insert(5, atIndex: 0)) // -> ()
print(intArray.removeAtIndex(0)) // -> 5

var colorDic = [String : String]()
print(colorDic.updateValue("Blue", forKey: "FirstColor")) // -> nil
print(colorDic.removeValueForKey("FirstColor"))// -> Optional("Blue")
```

BTW: why `updateValue` method for Dictionary returns `nil` not the `void`

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reasoning is that when you remove an element from an array or dictionary you might want to use that removed element for something, so having the function return that element allows you to store it in a variable if you need to.

However inserting an element requires you to already have that element, so there is no need for the function to return it.

As for the updateValue function for a dictionary, the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Dictionary_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structm/Dictionary/s:FVs10Dictionary11updateValueFTq_6forKeyx_GSqq__) reveal a bit more as to why it is nil in this case. If you are updating the value for a key that already has value, the function returns the value that was replaced (in case you need it for something). The function returns nil when there was no previous value, because you already have the element you updated it with, so there is no need for the function to return that to you.

Comment: thanks a lot for you explanation. I have a better understanding now

Answer (score -1):

They are designed for better code readability. It is a lot nicer for the eye if there is only one action on a line of code.

In other programming languages(ex. C++) it is common to chain calls to an object, and then on one line of code you can insert, delete and sort an array, which will lead to very bad readability and understanding of the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and explanation ")